# Using が multiple times in one sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-が

If you ask a question, such as 誰がこれが分かる？ Is this still grammatical? Is it okay to use two が's in the same sentence?

Comment: According to [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3521/4287) answer, yes it's grammatical

Comment: It may be grammatical but it is awefully unnatural.  Had to say it as no one else has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is grammatically correct.  But if you want to avoid multiple がs like this, you can replace the former with に.

> - 誰***に***これがわかる？

See also [this topic about が and に interchangeablitily](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4440/78).

Comment: Did you mean "the former one"? Also it's not possible to do this for all predicates.

Comment: Oops, yes.  I'll correct.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie What's an example where it's impossible?

Comment: ✗誰にこれが好きですか？. And it's not just a syntactic restriction, as this is fine: ○誰にこれが必要ですか？

Comment: Yeah, as Darius says, even if you forcibly interpret it, it only sounds "who do you want to do this to?". If you somehow want to avoid repetition, you may have 誰がこれを, but 誰がこれが is fine.